# Why is there different policies from the USA for Turkey vs Greece/ India?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, india, turkey, greece

- [Russian S-300s used by 3 NATO member countries](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/russian-s-300s-used-by-3-nato-member-countries/1449436)

According to the above link, the Russian S-300 missile defense system is being used by three NATO countries: Greece, Bulgaria, and Slovakia.

- [the USA ‘welcomes’ Greece’s interest in buying the F-35](https://www.flightglobal.com/fixed-wing/usa-welcomes-greeces-interest-in-buying-the-f-35/141431.article)

According to the above link, the USA is welcoming Greece's decision to purchase F-35.

- [How does Turkey's purchase of the S-400 anti-air system jeopardize the F-35?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/42018/32479)

According to the above link, the USA is worried that Turkey using S-400 and F-35 at the same time would give Russia the opportunity to collect data on F-35.

- [No blanket waiver of CAATSA sanctions for buying Russian/Chinese arms, but India safe, says the US](https://theprint.in/diplomacy/no-blanket-waiver-of-caatsa-sanctions-for-buying-russian-chinese-arms-but-india-safe-says-us/569406/)

According to the above link, the USA is soft in India for buying S-400.

Now, I have two questions here:

1. Since, Turkey is officially expelled from the F-35 project, why has the USA sanctioned Turkey for S-400?
2. Why is the same attitude as Turkey is not visible in the case of Greece and India by the USA?

Comment: Greece has not bough Russian missiles in a long time. So this is bit of a red herring. The rest of your q is basically  duplicate of your other one on India. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61006/why-is-india-purchasing-s-400-rather-than-the-us-made-missiles

Comment: And the US did oppose the sale to Cyprus at the time:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cypriot_S-300_crisis#Western_reactions The fact that those missiles ended up in Greece was the compromise.

Comment: Edit suggestion: First paragraph: Greece, Bulgaria and Greece. Greece appears twice. Comment: Has any country used (or is planning to use) both S-400 and F-35, except Turkey? Looks like those two systems can't be together according to the US.

Comment: @SeverusSnape, *First paragraph: Greece, Bulgaria, and Greece. Greece appears twice.* - it's corrected before you posted your comment.

Comment: *Has any country used (or is planning to use) both S-400 and F-35, except Turkey?* - so, what is the difference between using S-400 with F-35, and using S-300 with F-35?

Comment: @Fizz, purchasing, or possessing a Russian missile is not the issue here. The issue is Russia gathering intelligence through the hardware.

Comment: @user366312 That would be a separate question. I found [this page](https://www.defenseone.com/technology/2019/07/why-s-400-and-f-35-cant-get-along/158504/) however using a simple search. S-400 is more "evolved" than S-300 and probably "much much better". Why the Russians don't hesitate to sell it to even the Chinese, not just NATO countries could be because S-500 is likely to come into existence very soon. There could be other reasons. I am not so sure. About the edit suggestion: I didn't notice the change while I was typing.

Comment: Why should the policies be the same?

Comment: @ohwilleke, Because they all of them share the same issue: US alliance + Russian missile + US/NATO fighter jets.

Answer (score 4):

- Turkey is a NATO member. There *used* to be an understanding that all NATO members stood together against the Soviet Union. Russia isn't the Soviet Union, there is a new Cold War brewing, so a NATO member buying from Russia is seen as more serious than a third party buying from Russia.
- Turkey has access to classified NATO information. Presumably, Russian experts would have to look at the Turkish air defense system to integrate the S-400, and the rest of NATO is afraid that these experts might learn NATO secrets.

Comment: So, aren't Greece, Bulgaria, and Slovakia NATO members?

Comment: @user366312, ten or twenty years ago things looked differently. Quite a lot of the "Russian" gear in the Greek inventory is actually ex-GDR.

Comment: So, the issue is not Russian gears. The issue is the USA doesn't trust Turkey. On the other hand, the USA trusts Greece, Bulgaria, and Slovakia. Isn't it?

Comment: @user366312 no.

Comment: @user366312, the issue is not Russian gear, it is Russian experts to install their *latest* gear.