# What is the basic difference between Turkey using S-400 vs India purchasing S-400 or Greece using S-300?

Tags: united-states, turkey, sanctions, weapons

See: [Why is there different policies from the USA for Turkey vs Greece/ India?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/61004/32479)

My above question was closed. So, I am reformulating the question and posting it again.

---

- [Russian S-300s used by 3 NATO member countries](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/russian-s-300s-used-by-3-nato-member-countries/1449436)

According to the above link, the Russian S-300 missile defense system is being used by three NATO countries: Greece, Bulgaria, and Slovakia.

- [the USA ‘welcomes’ Greece’s interest in buying the F-35](https://www.flightglobal.com/fixed-wing/usa-welcomes-greeces-interest-in-buying-the-f-35/141431.article)

According to the above link, the USA is welcoming Greece's decision to purchase F-35.

- [How does Turkey's purchase of the S-400 anti-air system jeopardize the F-35?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/42018/32479)

According to the above link, the USA is worried that Turkey using S-400 and F-35 at the same time would give Russia the opportunity to collect data on F-35. However, we all know that Turkey is already out of the F-35 project.

- [No blanket waiver of CAATSA sanctions for buying Russian/Chinese arms, but India safe, says the US](https://theprint.in/diplomacy/no-blanket-waiver-of-caatsa-sanctions-for-buying-russian-chinese-arms-but-india-safe-says-us/569406/)

According to the above link, the USA is soft in India for buying S-400.

---

- [the US imposes sanctions on Turkey over the purchase of Russian air defense system](https://www.france24.com/en/americas/20201214-us-imposes-sanctions-on-turkey-over-purchase-of-russian-air-defence-system)

In light of the above links and information, What is the **basic** difference between Turkey using S-400 vs India purchasing S-400 or Greece/Bulgaria/Slovakia using S-300?

Comment: I don't see a new question. Turkey is still a NATO member and India still isn't. The new S-400 is still different from the old S-300, which is so old it predates the fall of the Iron Curtain. NATO "inherited" the S-300. Realistically, Turkey had the choice between the Patriot system, NASAMS or Aster, all of which are modern NATO-standardized systems, but presumably a ship-based system could also have been adapted.

Comment: @MSalters, Turkey says that it opted for Patriot, and the USA refused to sell. There is actually a video of Donald trump confirming their account.

Comment: @user366312: Turkey has invaded or threatened to invade almost all its neighboring countries in recent years, why would you expect it to be treaded the same as the peaceful countries you mention?

Comment: @user366312: AFAIK Turkey "opted" for the Patriot, but that didn't mean they actually wanted to buy those missiles from Raytheon. Instead, they wanted to buy the blueprint. This would turn them into a competitor of Raytheon. The US does allow the sales of the Patriot missile. Other NATO countries like Greece and the Netherlands have them, and have even stationed them in Turkey. But the design itself is not sold. This is quite common - missile technology has been very restricted since the Cold War. Even a civilian company like SpaceX has no foreign employees.

Comment: @MSalters,  between Turkey and the USA, someone is obviously lying. You can post an answer regarding this.